# Replicate result `func masking(_ mask: CGImage) -> CGImage?` by Core Image framework

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage, ciimage

Is there an option to replicate `func masking(_ mask: CGImage) -> CGImage?` from Core Graphics using CoreImage and one of `CIFilter`? I've tried `CIBlendWithMask` and `CIBlendWithAlphaMask` without success. Most important thing is that I need to preserve alpha channel, so I want image to be masked in such way, that if mask is black -> show Image, if mask is white -> transparent.
My masking code:

```
extension UIImage {
    
    func masked(by mask: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        guard let maskRef = mask.cgImage,
            let selfRef = cgImage,
            let dataProvider = maskRef.dataProvider,
            let mask = CGImage(
                maskWidth: maskRef.width,
                height: maskRef.height,
                bitsPerComponent: maskRef.bitsPerComponent,
                bitsPerPixel: maskRef.bitsPerPixel,
                bytesPerRow: maskRef.bytesPerRow,
                provider: dataProvider,
                decode: nil,
                shouldInterpolate: false),
            let masked = selfRef.masking(mask) else {
                    fatalError("couldnt create mask!")
        }
        let maskedImage = UIImage(cgImage: masked)
        return maskedImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. Key is to use image that has grayscale format, rgb and other will not work. Resizing step can be removed, if image and maks have the same size. Doable as extension, can be done as subclass of CIImage too. Enjoy:)

Of course It can be modified as extension to `UIImage`, `CIImage`, `CIFilter`, how You like it.

```
extension CGImage {
    
    func masked(by cgMask: CGImage) -> CIImage {
        let selfCI = CIImage(cgImage: self)
        let maskCI = CIImage(cgImage: cgMask)
        
        let maskFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIMaskToAlpha")
        maskFilter?.setValue(maskCI, forKey: "inputImage")
        let scaleFilter = CIFilter(name: "CILanczosScaleTransform")
        scaleFilter?.setValue(maskFilter?.outputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
        scaleFilter?.setValue(selfCI.extent.height / maskCI.extent.height, forKey: "inputScale")
        let filter: CIFilter! = CIFilter(name: "CIBlendWithAlphaMask")
        filter.setValue(selfCI, forKey: "inputBackgroundImage")
        let maskOutput = scaleFilter?.outputImage
        filter.setValue(maskOutput, forKey: "inputMaskImage")
        let outputImage = filter.outputImage!
        return outputImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own custom CIFilter. The tutorials:

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html)

[Apple Docs 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html)

[Raywenderlich.com Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5428948-core-image-from-ciimage-to-metal-and-beyond)

This is not trivial, but it pays off when you learn how to do it :)

Comment: Oh damn. Really. I’ve tried to use clear ciimage as input image and using image to filter as background, zero results. Maybe my mask is wrong. Maybe mask have to be one byte per pixel, grayscale image for mask?

Comment: I made it simple for CIImage :)